# Show status before refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When i select **checkbox** and click on "**Show Status**" button , its displaying **Status** value only after i refresh the page, but i need to show **before refresh** the page.

[image]

**html**

```html
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="assigneeid-<?php echo $orderrecords[$k][" tracking_id "]; ?>" onclick="assignorderids('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k][" tracking_id "]; ?>')" name="checkassigneeid" class="assigneeid-order" value="<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["
    tracking_id "]; ?>">
</td>
```

**javascript**

```js
$('#show_status').click(function() {
  var selected = [];
  $('.assigneeid-order:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
    $('.assigneeid-order').prop('checked', false);
  });

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selected);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api.php",
    data: {
      data: jsonString
    },
    success: function(response) {
      response = $.parseJSON(response);
      $.each(response, function(index, val) {
        $("#" + index + "").html(val);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**api.php**

```php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
$response = array();

foreach($data as $id) {
  $orderid = $id;
  $hide = '';
  $post_data['username'] = 'admin';
  $post_data['password'] = 'admin123';
  $post_data['awb'] = $orderid;
  $url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $orderResults = $xml = simplexml_load_string($output);

  foreach($orderResults - > object as $child) {
    $status = (string) $child - > field[10];
    break;
  }
  $res = explode("\n", $output);

  if (!isset($res[13])) {
    $res[13] = null;
  }

  $statusfinal = str_replace('<field type="CharField" name="status">', '', $status);
  if ($statusfinal != '') {
    $sqlecom = "UPDATE do_order set in_transit='".$status.
    "',tconformed_by='Ecom' where tracking_id=".$orderid;
    $db_handleecom = new DBController();
    $resultecom = $db_handleecom - > executeUpdate($sqlecom);
  }

  // store the responce in array 
  $response[$orderid] = $status;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Please help me to find solution, i am using mysqli....

Please let me know if you have any doubts.... Thanks in Advance.

**Update**

Before i was getting status values based on orderid instead of awb , you can see in above image  , that time status was showing before refreshing page. here is code for getting status based on Order ID....

```
$curl_data['username']='admin'; 
$curl_data['password']='admin123'; 


$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data'])); 
$response = array(); 

foreach($data as $id){ 

$orderid = $id; 
$curl_data['awb']=$orderid; 

$hide = '';
 $url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/?awb=awbnumber&order='.$orderid.'&username=admin&password=admin123'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 


$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
$res = explode("\n",$output); 

if ( ! isset($res[13])) 
{ 
$res[13] = null; 
} 



$status = str_replace('</field>','',$res[13]); 



$statusfinal = str_replace('<field type="CharField" name="status">','',$status); 
if($statusfinal!='') 
{ 
$sqlecom = "UPDATE do_order set in_transit='".$statusfinal."',tconformed_by='Ecom' where order_id=".$orderid; 
$db_handleecom = new DBController(); 
$resultecom = $db_handleecom->executeUpdate($sqlecom); 
} 

// store the responce in array 


$response[$orderid] = $statusfinal; 

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Update 2**

below **network** tab , i got response properly as https://pastebin.com/VpWsngnV

Comment: A. Is the response ok? You can see it in the `network` tab in devTools (In the popular browsers). B. It seems that you're trying to present the values in elements such as `#1`, `#2` etc. Do you have these elements in your DOM? Maybe it will be better to post your html too..

Comment: @MoshFeu before i was getting status values based on `orderid` instead of `awb` , you can see in image posted in question , that time `status` was showing before refreshing page : here is code : https://pastebin.com/1ZKwYsD0 , please check and tell me what wrong i done ?

Comment: @MoshFeu also in `response` its taking more time to give the results....

Comment: @MoshFeu is `Response` , it showing correct results, but in php page , status values are displaying only after refreshing page....

Comment: If the data returns from the server properly, the issue is in appending it to the page itself. As much as I can see, you are trying to append the data using `$("#" + index + "").html(val);`. That means that you have an element in the DOM with the id `0`, `1` etc. Do you have these elements in your DOM?